# Detect if UIViewController changed in UI hierarchy in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to detect if anything changes on `UIViewController` (current view) in the whole UI hierarchy?

I would like to shut off a certain service at background when user have touch/trigger any event in current view without knowing what interaction user provided. For example, I have a network service running at background when user first land on the view, if they swipe or navigate to other page, i need to close the service before the view changes happen.

Comment: You can rely on viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear of current controller

Comment: in this case, i will need to find the current view controller. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If your views number is changing you can simply use

```
        self.view.subviews
```

to check it after your operation.

If you just want to test when you first show or leave you can use ViewDidAppear() or ViewDidDisappear() to check you operation as Teja said.